# Dagger2 - where define the scopes

Tags: dagger-2

I have a small question to Dagger2.
But first let me show the sample code:

```
@Singleton
@Component(module={ApplicationModule.class})
public Interface ApplicationComponent {

}


@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return context;   
    }
}
```

I know that the objects from the component now are "Singletons"..
My question... Did that have any effect to the Module? Is the Module also Singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Module will not be singleton unless you specify the scope for the `@Provides` annotated provider methods as well.

```
@Singleton
@Component(module={ApplicationModule.class})
public Interface ApplicationComponent {
    Context context;
}


@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides //unscoped, every injection is new instance
    public Context context() {
        return context;   
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton //scoped, one instance per component
    public Something something() {
        return new Something();
    }
}
```